# Toggling Multiple IDs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with 2 columns of multiple divs. They are basically descriptions and the user can click the 'Read More' button to expand the description. The class 'long' would appear then. When the user clicks on another Read More div, I would like to the current div to close and the new one to expand. However, my jQuery is a little off as when I click one button, all the divs open up and when I click again all the divs close.

The third function is the one I need to rewrite so that I open the 1st div, only one opens and when I open the 2nd div, the 1st one closes. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Here is an excerpt of the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<section id="tom-box">
    <img class="image" src="img/tom.png" align="left">
    <h3>Person</h3>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <article class="short">Lorem ipsum. This part automatically shows.</article>

    <div class="long">This part is hidden until clicked on Read More button.
    </div>

    <a id="tom-button" class="button" href="javascript:;">
        <img src="img/more-arrow.png">Read More
        <img src="img/more-arrow.png">
    </a>
</section> 


<section id="bob-box">
    <img class="image" src="img/bob.png" align="left">
    <h3>Person</h3>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <article class="short">Lorem ipsum. This part automatically shows.</article>

    <div class="long">This part is hidden until clicked on Read More button.
    </div>

    <a id="bob-button" class="button" href="javascript:;">
        <img src="images/more-arrow.png">Read More
        <img src="images/more-arrow.png">
    </a>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function () {

function hidesections() {
    $("*[id*='-box'] .long").hide('medium');
};

function reset() {
    $("*[id*='-button']").html('<img src="images/more-arrow.png"> Read More <img src="images/more-arrow.png">');
};

$("*[id*='-read']").toggle(
    function() {
        $("*[id*='-box] .long").show('medium');
        reset();
        $("*[id*='-button']").html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
    }, function () {
        if ( $("*[id*='-box'] .long").css('display') == 'block')
        {
            hidesections();
            reset();
        }
        else {
            hidesections();
            reset();
            $("*[id*='-box'] .long").show('medium');
            $("*[id*='-button']").html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
        }   
});


})
```

Comment: Duplicate IDs anywhere on a page are invalid. jQuery can only see the first match. Best sort that out first (e.g. using classes instead) :)

Comment: You don't seem to have any kind of logic that says "The one that was clicked...". Without that, how will the code know what to act on?

Comment: Hi @TrueBlueAussie I am using a wildcard selector in the jQuery to select all the IDs that end -box or -read

Comment: You have duplicate IDs in `<article id="short">` and `<img id="image"`. For the other ones class matches will be much faster and cleaner.

Comment: Element `id`s should be unique. Use classes.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie good catch! Sorry about that. Missed that when I copied the first section over. Those are meant to be classes.

Comment: Also you have no ids ending with `-read` so I can't mockup a working example (as I am not sure what it is supposed to do) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I believe that should be fixed now in the jQuery!

Comment: `toggle(fn,fn)` is deprecated. Learn how to isolate instances of rows by using `this` in event handlers combined with traverses. Go through every traverse method in API to see examples ... will be time well spent

Comment: The jQuery references IDs containing `-read` but the HTML does not have those. Please try mockup a JSFiddle etc with the correct HTML :)

Comment: ok, looking at the code and the question, where is the html for anything with a class of summary and where is your click event binding?

Answer (score 1):

i believe this is the implementation you would like: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/53/

html:

```
<section id="tom-box">
    <img class="image" src="img/tom.png" align="left"/>
    <h3>Person</h3>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <article class="short">Lorem ipsum. This part automatically shows.</article>

    <div class="long">This part is hidden until clicked on Read More button.
    </div>

    <a class="button more" href="#">
        <img src="img/more-arrow.png"/> Read More <img src="img/more-arrow.png"/>
    </a>
    <a class="button less" href="#">
        <img src="images/less-arrow.png"/> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png"/>
    </a>
</section>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.more').on('click', function() {
        console.log('more clicked');
        $('.long').hide();
        $('.more').show();
        $('.less').hide();
        $(this).closest('section').find('.long').show();
        $(this).closest('section').find('.more').hide();       
        $(this).closest('section').find('.less').show();      
    });
    $('.less').on('click', function() {
        console.log('less clicked');
        $(this).closest('section').find('.long').hide();
       $(this).closest('section').find('.more').show();       
        $(this).closest('section').find('.less').hide();
    });
});
```

css:

```
.long {
    display:none;
}
.less {
    display:none;
}
```

first off, like everyone else was saying, you cannot have the same id multiple times on the page, therefore the first change is to change the id="image" and id="short" to class="image" and class="short".

the css i added is just to make sure that none of the long divs display in the beginning.

EDITED to capture whole scope of question in answer (read less functionality)
hope this helps

when class more is clicked, it hides all class long divs, and less buttons, then shows the current long div and less button and hides its own show more button.

also, i added the less button instead of adding it through jquery. on less button click, it hides its own less button and its long div and shows its more button.

note the css for the less class that is added to hide all less buttons upon load of page.

Comment: oh sorry, let me modify, i didnt capture the whole scope of the question

Comment: @user3097331, is this answer what you're looking for?

Comment: your code is a lot less complex and more understandable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little simpler answer.  The basic idea is that you toggle the `show-more` class on the container, then your css can turn on and off buttons and text as needed based on that parent class.

Additionally, if you wanted animations (slide out or whatever), you can easily attach those to the `.show-more` class stuff in the css.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.more, .less').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var currentSection = $(this).closest('section');
    $('section').not(currentSection).removeClass('show-more'); 
    $(this).closest('section').toggleClass('show-more')
  });
});
```

```css
.long {
    display:none;
}
.show-more .long {
    display:block;
}
.button.less {
    display: none;
}
.show-more .button.more {
    display:none;
}
.show-more .button.less {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="tom-box">
    <img class="image" src="img/tom.png" align="left"/>
    <h3>Person</h3>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <article class="short">Lorem ipsum. This part automatically shows.</article>
    
    <div class="long">This part is hidden until clicked on Read More button.
    </div>
    
    <a class="button more" href="#">
        <img src="img/more-arrow.png"/> Read More <img src="img/more-arrow.png"/>
    </a>
    <a class="button less" href="#">
        <img src="images/less-arrow.png"/> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png"/>
    </a>
</section> 


<section id="bob-box">
    <img class="image" src="img/bob.png" align="left"/>
    <h3>Person</h3>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <article class="short">Lorem ipsum. This part automatically shows.</article>
    
    <div class="long">This part is hidden until clicked on Read More button.
    </div>
    
    <a class="button more" href="#">
        <img src="img/more-arrow.png"/> Read More <img src="img/more-arrow.png"/>
    </a>
    <a class="button less" href="#">
        <img src="images/less-arrow.png"/> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png"/>
    </a>
</section>
```

Comment: your answer is simpler, but it doesnt cover the full scope of the situation, OP said: "When the user clicks on another Read More div, I would like to the current div to close and the new one to expand."

Comment: oh right.  it did seem too simple.  i'll see what i can do

Comment: Edited - I think I got it now.